# How to display data in datagrid from mysql in multiple forms?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, datagrid, xampp

I have 2 forms, in the first form the datagrid populates with data in mysql. Then to repeat this for my second form I copied the code over and changed all variable names, but when I load the form the datagrid is not populated with mysql data, it doesn't even throw an error. Here is the code I used for my first form and below is for my second form.

This is the code for the second form, where it doesn't work, the code is exactly the same (changed variable names) for the first form.

Second form:

```
Public Class frmShareholderDetails
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection
Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim mycommandbuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder
Dim mycommand As MySqlCommand
Dim datatable As New DataTable
Dim dataset As New DataSet
Dim mydatagridviewprinter As datagridviewprinter
Dim objconnection As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password=")
'declaring variables


Private Sub frmShareholderDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    connection.ConnectionString =
        ("Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password=")

    Try
        connection.Open()
        'opens connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Cannot connect to BA-Solutions Database")
    End Try

    myadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand
    myadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection
    myadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Shareholder_Details"
    'creates adapters
    mycommandbuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(myadapter)
    myadapter.Fill(datatable)
    myadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    dataset = New DataSet
    myadapter.Fill(dataset, "Shareholder_Details")
    rowposition = 0
    DGVShareholder.DataSource = dataset.Tables("Shareholder_Details")
    'sets datasource
    connection.Close()
    'close connection

    Dim recordsondisplay As Integer
    recordsondisplay = DGVShareholder.RowCount
    lblRecords.Text = recordsondisplay & " records in database."
End Sub
```

End Class

Can anyone see where the problem lies? I have been using trial and error, but no solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I managed finally to get it work, by deleteing the whole code and adding bits at a time, I think the error lay in the connection section of the code, thanks for your suggestions anyway.